# SQL Error (126): Incorrect key file for table '.\mysql\user.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

To give you a bit more info I had moved my webserver from my C: drive to my D: drive and had upgrade my OS from Server 2008 to 2012.

All my website are fine and load without an issue and I havent run into any weird issues with them.

I will get this error in the title when I try to add a database to specific sql user or even add a new sql user all together.

Also tried a copy of my webserver on a VM with Windows 7 as the OS and did not get this issue so I think its something with Server 2012 but not sure what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Upvoted; this question isn't perfect, but it doesn't deserve a -3 score...

Answer (score 7):

When using MyISAM, messages like that usually occur after a power failure (or other crash of mysqld).

```
USE mysql;
CHECK TABLE user;
REPAIR TABLE user;
```